# Overwriting variables in t4

Tags: c#, t4

I have a structure of 3 layers of inheritance of t4 templates I'm using to generate configs. The goal is to generate web.configs

**Global.tt** (to be added to every config file):

```
<customErrors mode="<#= CustomErrors#>
<#+ string CustomErrors = "On"; #> // Set a default value ✓
```

**EnvironmentSpecific.TT** can then override this value:

```
<#@include file="..\Global.tt" #>
<# CustomErrors = "Off"; #> //Override the default value ✓
```

*Up to this point everything works fine*

**ServerSpecific.TT**

```
<#@include file="..\EnvironmentSpecific.tt" #>
<# CustomErrors = "On"; #> // Does not override ✕
```

**Problem:** ServerSpecific.config will have CustomErrors off as it won't override variables defined in the parent.

If I only want to override this value for 1 server without touching the rest of the environment, the only solution I have at the moment is to remove the override(CustomErrors = "On") from the EnvironmentSpecific.TT and add it (CustomErrors = "Off/On") to all 20 ServerSpecific.TT

It is very frustrating and feels like there should be a simple solution

Comment: What do you mean `overwrite` or `override`? Include *includes* another script, it doesn't define any inheritance relation. Your code *assigns* different values to `CustomErrors`. Do you mean that the last assignment doesn't happen?

Comment: Not sure I understand the difference between override vs overwrite in this case. I want the value from the lowest level template to go into the config, but at the moment it doesn't... Latest assignment doesn't happen.

I understand it's not inheritance in traditional sense but since one is spawned from another you can see the parent/child relationship there...

Comment: There is no relationship at all, just inclusion of files. The template code is executed as it is encountered. `<#+` does define a field at the template level, but `<customErrors mode="<#= CustomErrors#>` is written out whenever `Global.tt` is included and the line encountered. In fact, all templates should write out `mode='On'`

Comment: Are you trying to emulate ASP.NET publishing profiles?